# what i need to pass for session.token of QBASession in QuickBlox

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am stuck at passing `token` for `session`. What do I need to pass as a token?

```
QBASession *session = [QBASession new];
session.token = @"f23d03bd2341a1f923b7d4c1fbee97af1cd296f2";
```

Is the `token` is a random number?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the token in the QuickBlox Dashboard and then you can get the new token using the following API Call :

```
[[QBSession currentSession] startSessionWithDetails:session updateSessionBlock:{
//
// Execute synchronous URL request to retrieve new token from custom server
//
// Until the end of this block all the operations will be paused
QBASession *updatedSession = [QBASession new];
session.token = @"new token";

[[QBSession currentSession] startSessionWithDetails:updatedSession];

//
}];
```

Quote from official documentation :

> It's also possible to initialise the SDK with an existent QuickBlox
>   token